# INotifyPropertyChanged boggs down when handling a lot of data

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a HID device that I am communicating with at around 200hz-600hz and is interpreting data into a class object that represents the HID device properties. The class implements INotifyPropertyChanged on its properties and due to the communication speed I think the processing queue is getting bogged down as controls seem to become laggy and "framey" after a couple minutes.

Are there methods in place in .net that may help in matters such as this, perhaps a event handler pool or queue of some sort?

Unfortunately without my HID device I'm not sure my code is of any use to anybody to replicate, but ill include a couple relevant snippets just to show my implementation:

```
public enum DataEvents { onNone = 0, onStatus = 1, onInput = 2, onOutput = 4, onReport = 8};
public class Controller: INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable, INotifyDisposed
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler Disposing;
    public event EventHandler Disposed;
    public event EventHandler ReportReceived;

    internal void callPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    internal void callReportReceived()
    {
        ReportReceived?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool Touch1
    {
        get { return _Touch1; }
        private set { if (value != _Touch1) { _Touch1 = value; if (RaiseUpdateEvents.HasFlag(DataEvents.onInput)) callPropertyChanged("Touch1"); } }
    }
    private bool _Touch1 = false;

    //There are many more properties but all of them follow this pattern, and have several different types
}
```

My object is populated from a `System.Threading.Thread` on a loop that polls the HID device for reports, The HID devices read method is a blocking call so the loop is not a death loop and is limited to the data rate of the device, as stated usually 200hz-600hz.

EDIT: Worth noting that yes, I am specifically interested in WPF bindings.

Comment: If this is Wpf, you are causing a backlog on the dispatcher. Raise the event less often

Comment: @Gusdor Well the event is raised when the HID device property changes, so how would i mitigate that

Comment: @Gusdor Im thinking a queue for each property where if multiple events are raised for a property it will clear all but the most recent, but I cant see how that wont add lag and delay in itself especially at these speeds.

Comment: Rather than using INotifyPropertyChanged directly on the object updated by the HID, set a DispatcherTimer with a reasonnable rate (maybe ticking every 100 ms or so). When it ticks, read the property of the object, and use it to update another object that will be bound to the UI.

Comment: You are going to need to introduce a produce-consumer implementation. Consider libraries such as Reactive Extensions or Data Flow.

Comment: A dispatch timer of some sort would introduce its own latency of <=100ms if set to 100ms, I would rather take an approach where when it is ready to process dispatches for a specific property, it ignores all but the most recent. Would also like to avoid external libraries if possible and keep it .net if I can.

Comment: @Wobbles Please define '.Net'? Both of those suggestions are targeted for .Net. Data Flow is even a Microsoft offering. Both are designed for low latency, high frequency signalling, asynchronous consumption and buffering. These days, you really need to pull in 3rd party stuff when you can - especially when its free. That's just money in the bank.

Comment: @Gusdor They may be .net libraries, but they are still external unmanaged libraries.

Comment: @Wobbles Please define unmanaged. Are you concerned because you do not own the code? That is an unhealthy stance for most businesses. Owning less code is usually desirable. You don't own the .Net framework code. Or the operating system, or (probably) the device drivers that power your USB device. Are you writing safety critical or financial software?

Comment: You are starting from _"the data rate of the device ... 200hz-600hz"_ But the WPF/GUI is designed for Humans with an absorption rate <= 20Hz. So base your design on this, accumulate your data and sample with a timer no shorter than 100ms.

Comment: @Wobbles, **unmanaged** in the context of the .Net ecosystem means you are using native libraries that execute outside of the CLR.  Any .Net library compiled for .Net is _managed_.  Using that word to describe anything else in this context is confusing.  Please don't.

Answer (score 10):

When dealing with near real time systems in WPF (I spent the last 6 years working on them), you have a couple options.  First, I'll list a couple bits of food for thought:

- To get all WPF bindings to update through one event use `string.Empty` as your property name.
- Your problem may not entirely be due to events.  WPF has quite a few gotchas that affect memory management.

So the question you have to ask is how often does the user need to see any kind of change?  Human persistence of vision is 1/10th of a second, or 100ms.  Any update more frequent than that is wasted, but more often than not, even that is too frequent.

**One Event Per Second?**

In my scenario, we determined that we only needed to update everything on screen once a second.  Even though we received data up to 12 times a second (83ms per sample), we collected and averaged the data to smooth it out.  It provided a better sense of what was going on for our users.

- We architected our view models to call an `Update()` method once a second with a master timer.
- The models implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` to avoid a [binding memory leak](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micmcd/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic/), but only raised the one property change event with `string.Empty` to cause the UI to refresh

**Minimize Object Creation**

Every millisecond spent in garbage collection is a noticeable amount of time the user can't interact with your application.  Every time you raise an event, you have to create the event object you are sending.  While you technically can create the event object once and raise the same instance, there are several places where WPF creates object instances for you.  These are things you need to keep an eye on:

- `DataTemplate` essentially creates a new template for each object you want to template.  Try to use virtualization if possible, and minimize the use of this.
- `ResourceDictionary` every time you declare a resource dictionary in a control you are creating a new instance.  It's better to have all your merged resource dictionaries in your `App.xaml` than to keep including the same dictionaries in different user controls.  Particularly if you have the user control in a `DataTemplate`
- `ContentPresenter` is not your friend.

To explain a bit further, `ContentPresenter` will take your object, look up it's type in the control's `ResourceDictionary` to find the `DataTemplate` to instantiate for your data.  It can be convenient when you need to swap out a specific part of your window for another control, however it does come at a significant cost.  Minimize it's use whenever possible.

**Keep Hardware/Communication in the Background**

We set up threads specifically to handle the communications and processing needs.  This lets the UI remain responsive while we can do a bit of DSP/statistical reduction on the data.

**Use a Memory Profiler**

Any time you need near real time updates on your display, you have to be particularly careful with memory use.  This has been the number one problem we've had to contend with.

- Your application starts out OK, but after a minute or two it starts degrading
- Make sure you aren't holding on to object instances that you don't expect
- Look for objects that survive garbage collection events

Answer (score 1):

Lets do something simple. One way or another, you are going to need to *downsample* your data. Displaying data on the UI at 200hz-600hz is usually going to cause issues.

My suggestion - start a timer of your choice with the longest duration you are OK with. Lets start with 1000ms.

1. Each time the timer expires, fire the event off for all your
   property changed events
2. Do not raise the property changed events when the device updates

Once per second, your processing will update and your application will stay responsive.

Comment: For hardware interaction, even so much as a 100ms timer is unacceptable. I think my key is some sort of queue where if events for a propery do start to stack up it only takes the most recent value.

Comment: @Wobbles 100ms should be absolutely fine. 20ms should work well too. The important thing is that you are not running _as fast as possible_ as this will always cause a bottleneck somewhere. I gave 1 second as an example because it will be very visible on the UI and in any debug logging you may put out.

Comment: "hardware interaction" on that scale should not be coupled to the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of good information been discussed here, but as far as implementation, this is the way I went:

```
    private Thread PropertyChangedQueueThread;
    private List<string> ChangedPropertiesQueue = new List<string>();
    private ManualResetEvent PropertyChangedQueueBlocker = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void PropertyChangedQueueWorker()
    {
        while (!this.disposingValue)
        {
            PropertyChangedQueueBlocker.WaitOne();

            string PropName = ChangedPropertiesQueue.Last();
            ChangedPropertiesQueue.RemoveAll(i => i == PropName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));

            if (ChangedPropertiesQueue.Count() == 0)
                PropertyChangedQueueBlocker.Reset();
        }
    }

    internal void QueuePropertyChangedEvent(string PropertyName)
    {
        ChangedPropertiesQueue.Add(PropertyName);
        PropertyChangedQueueBlocker.Set();
    }
```

Seems to work very well and it seems self scale-able so no matter how many property changes come in, only the most recent is ever displayed to the UI. Unless I am imagining the performance increase it seems to be working well for my needs.

I'm not quite sure what kind of performance loss I am getting using a List and .RemoveAll since each call to RemoveAll re-indexes the list as I understand it. Perhaps a type that indexes on a key that can be a string is better suited such as Dictionary

Comment: You can reduce complexity by only sending `string.Empty` as your property name.  This avoids the potential trap of parts of your UI not updating because the property name happened to be buried and discarded.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch you mean in the final event invoke?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Performance tanked when doing that, suspect there are too many properties and not all of them constantly change for a blanket update to have any performance value.

Comment: yes for the final event invoke.  Your PropertyChangedQueueBlocker is doing the rate throttling, which is primary.  The queue itself (`List<string> ChangedPropertiesQueue`) can be replaced with a simple `bool RaisedPropertyChanged`.  That prevents sending a property change when nothing changed.  If you are saying performance tanks when you have all that in place, something else is not right.  Shouldn't be a performance change one way or the other.

Comment: ..." performance change one way or the other" ... Meant to say that the performance of the eventing should be similar.  The key here is limiting the rate of the updates.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch the empty string forces a dispatcher to update ALL properties of the object, even ones that do not have a data change, this massive additional load on the dispatcher completely tanks performance. Does far better without trying to blindly force update all properties, and even so, forcing a property to update that hasnt actually changed can cause implementation issues for me down the line.